# Passing params to method from url

Tags: php, url

I'm writing my own framework (for learning) and I am at the stage where I want to pass parameters to a method. at the moment I'm achieving this via:

```
$params = array_slice($url, 1);
$class->{$method[1]}($params);
```

then in the method of the class I have `$params = func_get_arg(0);`
This works but is not ideal, I notice that in Codeigniter you can call

`http://domain.com/controller/method/p1/p2/p3`...

then in the method you get these via

`method($p1, $p2, $p3){}`

This is what I would prefer. How would I set this up?

*ps: my classes all extend a base class*

Comment: within a class that extends `baseclass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the hood, I'm betting CI uses [`call_user_func_array()`](http://us.php.net/call_user_func_array) to do this:

```
call_user_func_array( array( $class, $method[1]), $params);
```

Now, depending on the number of parameters in the array, you could have methods like you hinted at:

```
method($p1, $p2, $p3){}
```

Assuming there were 3 parameters in the `$params` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
call_user_func_array( array( $class, $method ), $params );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass an array that contains all your paramters instead of trying to pass all parameters one by one ?